# Undeclared variable in function

Tags: c

```
//Function to store select_field
void store_field(int num_fields, unsigned long *lengths, 
    MYSQL_ROW row, char elect_type[10][100]) 
{
    //Storing select_field below
    int i,j,k,g;
    for( i=1;i < num_fields;i=i+10)
    { 
        // i+10 so that loop is executed one time only, 
        // i=1 bcoz 2nd entry is select_type
        for (j=0;j<lengths[i];j++)
        {
            if (row[i] != NULL)
            {
                select_type[k][j] = *row[i];
                row[i]++; 
            }

            if (row[i] == NULL) 
            { 
                select_type[k][j]= '\0';
                printf ( "NULL\n");
                break; // row[i] is null for fields containing NULL
            }
        }
        for (j;j<100;j++)
        {
            select_type[k][j]='\0';
        } 
            // setting every other empty field in current row 
            // of select_type to NULL   
    }
    k++; 
}   
g = k; //HERE I AM GETTING THE ERROR 
for (k;k<10;k++){for(j=0;j<100;j++)
{
    select_type[k][j]='\0'; 
}
}
```

I have already declared `k` in the function but I am getting the error.

Comment: If you format your code, it will be much easier to read and understand.

Comment: You might provide a little documentation about what you are trying to do and where you think it's failing. If you can't compile your code please post the errors your compiler is presenting

Comment: When you ask a question about compiler or linker errors, please provide the *complete* and *unedited* error messages.

Comment: Please tell us exactly the compiler error message. You should re-indent your code. [Take a look at the SSCCE page](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I don't know about errors, but you should get lots of warnings about using uninitialized variables. You never initialize `k`, so it will have a seemingly random value, and when you use it it's undefined behavior. Using it as an array index may (and most probably will) lead to crashes.

Comment: Be honest. Do you understand the way the code is formatted? I don't, and many others don't as well. First rule of programming: Write your code in a way you'll still understand in a year or two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got an extra closing bracket. The line

```
}     g=k; **//HERE I AM GETTING THE ERROR**
```

closes the function.

---

I took the liberty of formatting out the code indentation. If you maintain good indentation it should be clear that the `}` is out of place:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>  // For tolower() function  //

//Function to store select_field
void store_field(int num_fields,unsigned long *lengths,MYSQL_ROW row,char select_type[10][100]){
 //Storing select_field below
    int i,j,k,g;

for( i=1;i < num_fields;i=i+10){ // i+10 so that loop is executed one time only , i=1 bcoz 2nd entry is select_type
    for (j=0;j<lengths[i];j++){
        if (row[i] != NULL){ select_type[k][j] = *row[i];
            row[i]++; 
        }

         if (row[i] == NULL) { select_type[k][j]= '\0'; printf ( "NULL\n");break; // row[i] is null for fields containing NULL
     }

    }for (j;j<100;j++){select_type[k][j]='\0';}    //setting every other empty field in current row of select_type to NULL   

} k++; 
//   }     g=k; **//HERE I AM GETTING THE ERROR** 
for (k;k<10;k++){for(j=0;j<100;j++){select_type[k][j]='\0'; }}    

}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you get "not in a function", that means that the code being flagged is, wait for it, not in a function.

Probably a mis-matched closing brace (`}`) that causes your function to end before you think it does.

I gave up on re-formatting your code to find the problem.

Comment: *If you get "not in a function", that means that the code being flagged is, wait for it, not in a function* My mind exploded when I read that.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Sorry to shock you. :) I get a bit frustrated sometimes when there *is* an error, which *does* say what is wrong, and it just doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should always indent your code to avoid this kind of error. You can find different indentation styles, choose the one you like the most

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

There are also automatic indentation tools, below is your code correctly indented

```
void store_field(int num_fields,unsigned long *lengths,MYSQL_ROW row,char select_type[10][100])
{

   int i,j,k,g;

   for( i=1;i < num_fields;i=i+10)
   { 
      for (j=0;j<lengths[i];j++)
      {
         if (row[i] != NULL)
         { 
            select_type[k][j] = *row[i];
            row[i]++; 
         }

         if (row[i] == NULL) 
         { 
            select_type[k][j]= '\0'; 
            printf ( "NULL\n");
            break; // row[i] is null for fields containing NULL
         }

      }
      for (j;j<100;j++)
      {
         select_type[k][j]='\0';
      }    
   } 
   k++; 
}     

g=k; **//HERE I AM GETTING THE ERROR** 
for (k;k<10;k++){for(j=0;j<100;j++)
{
   select_type[k][j]='\0'; 
}

}    

}
```

All the errors and extra brackets become evident immediately. Check for some code style guides, there many, choose one you like and stick to that one.